# greasemonkey: changing the 'preload' attribute of a 'video' markup in html source

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I get webpages with this in the source:

```
<video src="..." style="..." preload="metadata"></video>
```

and I wish firefox to handle it as:

```
<video src="..." style="..." preload="none"></video>
```

1. Is greasemonkey the best way?
2. How do I actually do it (I have no knowledge of JavaScripts)?
3. Will it help accelerate page loading time / use less memory? (I open a quite a few tabs at the same time and firefox seems to have hard times with it)
4. I see the  markup only when I use the Firebug tool in firefox. I don't see it as part of the html page source when I click "View Page Source". How is it possible? And will greasemonkey actually work in such a situation?

Comment: *I have no knowledge of JavaScripts* - in this case you need to download a firefox plugin here.  StackOverflow is **NOT** a free script writing service. As per #4 of your questions (you should try to ask one question per post), the reason is that most pages generate lots of HTML after loading using scripts. View page source displays HTML as it was received from the server.

Comment: OK. I will take it into mind in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much info about the video. I'll assume here you want to do this for all videos. In that case, your best bet is to try to do it after page loads:

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName(video);
for(var i=0,l=videos.length; i<l; i++) {
    videos[i].preload = "none";
}
```

This is basically what you asked for. Whether it will make anything better for you, that I cannot know.

Comment: That seems much more obvious now.
I will try that.
Thanks!